# Signed app distributed locally and then published to google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I distributed an app locally. I mean I signed the app and then I installed it manually into few devices, let´s say app version 1.1

I have published the app two days ago, let´s say version 1.2, on the `Google Play Store`, I used the same key also I have changed the `versionName` and the `versionCode` but the devices who have the version 1.1 do not get the latest version.

With a device with version 1.1 going to `Google Play Store` App place (I mean with the device going to `Google Play Store` and searching the app name)  I can see in details version 1.2 but I have just two buttons "uninstall" and "open" , nothing about update, this is a google play app picture

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you by chance using Google Play App Signing as well? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: If it is signed using the same key and have same digital print, it should update. But before that did you check the app version of the app installed on your phone? Maybe it got updated automatically over the wifi.

Comment: @ASN The same key has been used....digital print? On android studio I did -> Build->generated signed APK, I did not have choice for digital print

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly No, I am not . Do you recomment it to my case?

Answer (score 0):

- If the app has never been installed from the Play store for that user account it won't update
- If the app is signed with a different key from the Play store it won't update.

In general, only apps that were installed from Google Play will be updated by Google Play.

Comment: well I have tested and I installed an app directly from my pc, lets say version 1, after that I uploaded the version 2 to google play store and the app was updated both was signed with the same key.