# Can be updated an app installled outsite Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

Let´s say I have an app whose name is MyApp signed whit a key (my_key_app) and I transfer MyApp from my computer to my Android device (Samsung Galaxy) and I install it. The first app version have been installed on my device outsite `Google Play Store`

If I developed an update on MyApp and I push the update with the `versionName` and `versionCode` increased and signed with the same key (my_key_app)  on `Google Play Store`,  Should my Samsung galaxy updated from Gloogle Play Store?
In afirmative case,  Will it be updated automatically or I have to set something on Google play Console?

Comment: maybe you could do something like coding a method in your launcher activity that checks the installed version vs version on google play! and if they don't match then it takes user to app store and ask for update there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is signed with the same key, has the same package name and has higher versionName and versionCode, yes, it can be updated through Play Store. And if you has automatic updates on Play Store, it will be updated automatically.

EDIT:

Here is a video demonstrating the process works fine: [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/125divyuKgZRl1MUjgBuJ7Cdk6XnJaRde/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: did you tried it? I have read the vicerverse as well, he leído lo contrario  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170224/signed-app-distributed-locally-and-then-published-to-google-play-store/50225305#50225305

Comment: I do it frequently in all my apps when we release a major update. So I can ensure an app installed via ADB can be updated afterwards through Play Store. And I say more, I've just tested it again with one of my applications and it works. I've not tested automatic update yet. @JoseCuervas

Comment: ADB? what do you mean? I created a signed app using a  key  on  Build-> generated signed apk

Comment: ADB is the tool used to communicate PC with device, it means that I can install a generated signed apk with ADB command line over the wire. How do you install your generated signed apk in your device? You can install the app as you want, it'll work.

Comment: Transfering the app from my Pc to my Tablet using the microUsb wire

Comment: Ok, there is no problem, also works. I've just tested.

Comment: No in my case :( does not work,  on google play store I can just see the open button or uninstall . Do you do something "special" in those cases ?¿

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171453/discussion-between-jocuto-and-marc-estrada).